# Using for-loop to insert i into variable names?

Tags: python, for-loop, variables

I'm trying to use a for-loop to create a lot of plots. Long story aside, I need to create a script that does something similar to this example:

```
text1="Hello"
text2="my"
text3="name"
text4="is"
text5="John"


for i in range(0,6):
    print(text{i})
```

Which would output the following:

```
 #Output:
    'Hello'
    'my'
    'name'
    'is'
    'John'
```

Is this possible in Python?
Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to use a list instead of multiple variables.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny That also depends on the variables being defined in the scope where you call `vars()`, which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: And *in general*, it's not. There are many corner cases which will work with one proposed hack, but not another. Providing such a hack without mentioning the exceptions does no one any good, and promotes the idea that doing something like this is anything other than a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a list, not a bunch of similarly named variables.

```
texts = ["Hello", "my", "name", "is", "John"]
for t in texts:
    print(t)
```